# How to validate the missing records in Hive after sqooping the data from Oracle

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

Wanted to know how to check missing records in Hive when data is loaded from Oracle due to some issue.

Suppose:

Oracle no.of records : 2000
Hive no.of records : 1990

How to check the 10 missing records in Hive.

Answer (score 1):

Export from Oracle to a CSV file with a sort by primary Key. Same with HIVE. And a small UNIX diff. Bottom line, Sqoop cannot miss records, so there's probably something wrong in your integration.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your source table in oracle was updated. Is so then you can do an incremental import for Sqoop.

1. What type of data do you have?
2. Do you have a date field in Oracle?

If yes then you can `group by year` and `count(*)` both in Hive and Oracle. You will see a year that is not matching, then use that year and do a `count(*)` for each of the months by doing `group by month`.